# Unable to download blob using AZ CLI in Pipeline - SAS value getting removed from SAS token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm using az cli task in the pipeline and trying to download zip from Storage blob with SAS token using below command, however during the execution the %2 and %3 getting removed from the token which then fails with an error "invalid token" Any help?

`az storage blob download --container-name testcontainer --name new.zip --file C:\Test\new.zip --account-name mansing --sas-token "sv=2019-03-28&si=test-v1.0.0&sr=b&sig=uityesfggjXAxG2tvNs7y88K%2FnKPMsO8iuKPGurEJtS4%3D"`

I believe SAS token is encoded already, so I can not encode or use escape char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind! I just found on "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#use-azcopy-in-a-script" that adding additional % next to existing % solves the project.